# HttpClient handshake stuck forever

Tags: java, multithreading, httpclient

```
public HttpResponseBean get(String url, Map<String, String> headers) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Sending get request...");

        HttpClient httpClient = null;
        try {
            int timeout = 30 * 1000; // 30 seconds
            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)
                    .setSocketTimeout(timeout).build();
            httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(url);

            if (headers != null) {
                for (Entry<String, String> entry: headers.entrySet()) {
                    httpGetRequest.addHeader(new BasicHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                }
            }

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
            HttpResponseBean hrb = new HttpResponseBean(response);
            logger.debug("Get response: Response: " + hrb.toString());
            return hrb;
        } finally {
            closeConnection(httpClient);
        }
    }
```

This works well most of the time...but once in a while it gets stuck on handshake and will take forever until the server(tomcat) is restarted.
As per this link looks like a bug -> [apache httpclient 4.3 not timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611528/apache-httpclient-4-3-not-timing-out)

Is there a way out of this? I am using httpclient 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way out of this? I am using httpclient 4.4.1

Here's the [associated bug on the Apache site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1478).  It looks like people have had problems with the 4.4.1 version:

> I had this issue with version 4.4.1. At first I ignored this thread because it was flagged as resolved in 4.3.

But this seemed to have been resolved in the **4.5.1 version**.  I'd encourage you to upgrade if possible.

> I encountered this issue on version 4.3.4. I upgraded to 4.5.1 and the issue was fixed there.

Here's additional information:

> In version 4.3.4, http:// worked fine and timed out after 1 second. With https, the request hangs beyond 1 seconds and hangs until the [...] server closes the TCP connection.
>
> In version 4.5.1, the [correct] http behaviour was identical, and on https I got the following exception: [...] `org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to localhost:6171 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Read timed out`

Hope this helps.